# How to bind RadioButtonList Item to ControlParameter

Tags: asp.net

How to bind selected RadioButtonList item to controlParameter for my query?

I have following, but getting `[OleDbException (0x80040e14): Missing operand.] System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) +1216113 ...`error.

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="first" ></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;Enter Account (Owner ID) Number with dashes if applicable.&nbsp;<br />     
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="second" ></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="third" ></asp:TextBox><br />
    ...
    ...
    <asp:RadioButtonList id="accountType" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem text="foo" value="foo" selected="true"/>
        <asp:ListItem text="bar" value="bar" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db.ProviderName %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE (ACCT = @first OR ACCT = @second OR ACCT = @third) AND unpaid > 0 AND type = @accountTypeSelect ORDER BY acct ASC" >
  <SelectParameters>           
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="first" Name="first" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue ="-1" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="second" Name="second" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue ="-1"/>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="third" Name="third" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue ="-1" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="accountType" Name="accountTypeSelect" PropertyName="SelectedValue" type="String"/>            
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can name control properties and added into your sql with @controlname, have a look at this link for examples [SqlDataSource.SelectParameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters?view=netframework-4.8)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db.ProviderName %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE (ACCT = @first OR ACCT = @second OR ACCT = @thrid) AND unpaid > 0 AND type = @accountTypeSelect ORDER BY acct ASC" >
  <SelectParameters>           
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="first" Name="first" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue ="-1" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="second" Name="second" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue ="-1"/>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="third" Name="third" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue ="-1" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="accountType" Name="accountTypeSelect" PropertyName="SelectedValue" type="String"/>            
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: please update your changed code so can check

Comment: the version this code is running on is:  Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4261.0

Just thought this old version may affect the syntax. I'm not a ASP.net guy, but just had to update this old code that we have for one time.

Comment: which line are you getting this error, is it happening when you run databind method? the other option would be hard code the values directly in your select and test also table names can be surrounded by [] brackets, is it sql database or something else?

Comment: When I add `@accountTypeSelect` this, the error is thrown. The db is running from a filebased .dbf sql.

Comment: let's change the   `type = @accountTypeSelect` to `type = @accountType` hope this works since radio button creates each list item, hope this time works